# PopUp Window appears only on activity created

Tags: android

Am Validating the form with EditText box & Save button, incase if edittext is empty i need to display the popup window. Here is the code:

```
//OnCreate Method:

Button btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){

   String sMiles = edtMiles.getText().toString();
   if(sMiles.isEmpty()){
     showPopup();
   }
});

public  void showPopup(){
  View popUpView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toast,null);
  mpopup = new PopupWindow(popUpView,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
  mpopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
  mpopup.showAtLocation(popUpView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

  Button b = (Button)popUpView.findViewById(R.id.error_ok);
  b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {    
    mpopup.dismiss();
  });
}
```

The problem is: When I launch this activity with edittext empty & click on save, The popup appears then I click OK button to dismiss it. Again when i click the save button, The pop up window doesnt appears & sometime even the activity hangs.
Now i go back & launch the activity again, For first time click on save pop up appears, after dismiss the pop up & Click on svae doesnt appears the pop up.

Please can Someone Suggest or point me Where am i wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is this if(sMiles.isEmpty())

Comment: EditTextBox (R.id.edtMiles).. AM checking whether this edittext is empty or not. If empty show pop up..

Comment: may be the sMiles is null. do check for (sMiles !=null). e.g you could do something like this: if(sMiles == null){showpopup();return;} if(sMiles.isEmpty())showPopup();

Comment: Have checked it.. While debugging i can see the pop up everytime when edittext is empty. But while running am facing problem.

Comment: Here's a library which is already tested: https://github.com/johnkil/Android-AppMsg